# Is there a way to map a VM to a domain name with Azure without a static public IP?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, azure-networking, azure-web-apps

I have a Go application that I would like to host on the public internet via Azure using a domain I own with another provider.

I realize the most straight forward way todo this is to spin up a VM, request a static, public IP for it and then point to the IP with a DNS record. I was wonder if there was a easier/cheaper way to do this? Could I point to a CNAME or does Azure have some sort of dynamic DNS service?

Basically I don't care if the public address changes, so long and DNS compensates for it automatically. I was hoping that this flexibility could potentially lower cost and allow for beneficial deployment scenarios in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an Azure VM you have the option to set up a DNS name, as per the docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/create-fqdn?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002404). You can then use this DNS name in a CNAME to point your custom name to the VM, no static IP required.